# python- function isn't called in a while loop

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, if-statement

```
noprob=["nothing","none","no damage"]

while True:
    q1=input("input your answer:")
    answer=q1.split(' ')`


    if any(a in answer for a in noprob):
        function()#wont call this
        break
    else:
        print("else statement")
        continue

def function():
    print("code now works")
```

my code won't call the function when it should. this code should recognize user input and output necessary actions.

new whole code: with added elif statement which i think is the problem with the code

```
`noprob=["nothing","none","no damage"]
something=["something","yes"]`

def function():
    print("code now works")`

def something():
    print("something, code works")
while True:
    q1=input("input your answer:")
    answer=q1.split(' ')`


    if any(a in answer for a in noprob):
        function()#wont call this
        break
    elif any(a in answer for a in something):
        something()
        break
    else:
        print("else statement")
        continue
```

Comment: i have put the function before the while loop and it works but when using exactly this in my main code it won't work

Comment: `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable` this is the error i get

Comment: On what input is it not working?

Comment: You also have to move your function definition over your while loop otherwise the code will break.

Comment: Is this python 2 or python 3? After looking at your prints, one assumes this is python 3 but there is a difference how input works on python 2 and 3.

Comment: What is your input? Or do you get the same error when you write `answer` in your code instead of getting with an input?

Comment: my input is a user input, and the code is designed to pick out keywords thats why i use `if any(a in answer for a in noprob):` and i get the same error either way

Comment: Most likely somewhere in your main code, you are shadowing one of built-in functions. Can you post your whole code please by editing your question? Because this code shouldn't get that error.

Comment: @haifzhan i have added an elif statement and then it comes up with the TypeError: `noprob=["nothing","none","no damage"]
something=["something","yes"]

def function():
    print("code now works")

def something():
    print("something, code works")
while True:
    q1=input("input your answer:")
    answer=q1.split(' ')


    if any(a in answer for a in noprob):
        function()#wont call this
        break
    elif any(a in answer for a in something):
        something()
        break
    else:
        print("else statement")
        continue
`

Comment: new code in question

Comment: are you still gettting the errros even you define the functions before you use them?

Comment: yes, i think the problem may be when i start to add the elif statements

Comment: but i'm not sure how to fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, your list and function both named `something`. Rename one and change your code accordingly.

```
something=["something","yes"]

def something(): #this one shadows your list and needs to be renamed
    print("something, code works")
```

For generator thingy, [Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#changes-in-python-behavior)

Answer (score 2):

Python executes code form top to bottom. So you won't get to execute `function` if you don't declare its definition before. move the function before the `while` loop.

```
noprob=["nothing","none","no damage"]

def function():
    print("code now works")

while True:
    q1=input("input your answer:")
    answer=q1.split(' ')


    if any(a in answer for a in noprob):
        function()#wont call this
        break
    else:
        print("else statement")
        continue
```